# bgiframe with jquery browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, bgiframe

Here is my old jQuery code using jQuery 1.5 version. works

```
jQuery.fn.ShowPageMask = function() { 
    var maskHeight = $(document).height(); 
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7) { 
        $('#pageMask').bgiframe(); 
    } 

    $('#pageMask').css({ 'filter': "alpha(opacity=50)" }); 
    $('#pageMask').css({ '-moz-opacity': "0.6" }); 
    $('#pageMask').css({ '-khtml-opacity': "0.6" }); 
    $('#pageMask').css({ 'opacity': "0.6" }); 
    $('#pageMask').show(); 
    $(window).resize(function() { 
        $('#pageMask').setFullWidth(); 
    });
```

Now we updated to jQuery 1.9.1 recently and getting error `$.browser`

Here instead of checking the browser version and name, we should check the feature support. But i dont really understand, how can I check this below scenario with feature.. What feature i should detect?

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7) { 
    $('#pageMask').bgiframe(); // why the hell it is for IE<7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

**1)  Unless you still need to support IE6, you can just remove these three lines:**

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7) { 
    $('#pageMask').bgiframe(); 
}
```

---

**2) The current version of the plugin already tests for IE 6 and is, by default, only active if the browser is IE 6.  It uses the userAgent string to identify IE 6.**

So, you can change this:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7) { 
    $('#pageMask').bgiframe(); 
}
```

to just this:

```
$('#pageMask').bgiframe();
```

And, it will simply do nothing for browsers that aren't IE 6.

---

**3) If you wanted to use feature detection, you would need to devise a feature detection algorithm for the very problem that this plug-in is trying to fix.**  If the problem is present, then use the plug-in.  If the problem is not persent, then you don't need the plug-in.  I don't quite understand what problem the plug-in is trying to fix so I'm not sure how to advise you here.